# ASP.NET mvc 3 razor : Html Helper Extension Method - executed but dosen't print html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have problem with my html helper extension method in razor view engine. I want to render SideMenu if I have any nodes to print:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
@using MyNamespace.Helpers
<body>
    <div id = "page" style = "width: 90%; margin: 0 auto" class="pageSection">
        <div id="logo" class="pageSection">aaaa</div>
        <div id = "LeftMenuContainer">
        @{ if (ViewBag.Menu.LeftMenu.Count > 0)
           {
               Html.RenderSideMenu((ICollection<MyNamespace.MenuNode>)(ViewBag.Menu.LeftMenu));
           }
         }
         </div>
        <div id="content" class="pageSection">@RenderBody()</div>
        <div id="footer" class="pageSection"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderSideMenu(this HtmlHelper helper, ICollection<MenuNode> nodes)
{
    string result = "<h3>Menu</h3>";
    result += "<ul class=\"SideMenu\">";
    foreach (var node in nodes)
        result += MenuRenderEngine.RenderNode(node);
    result += "</ul>";
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result);
}
```

The problem is that method is executed and returns well prepared string but doesn't print it in view so I'm confused what did I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@` if you want to output the result on the page:

```
<div id = "LeftMenuContainer">
    @if (ViewBag.Menu.LeftMenu.Count > 0)
    {
        @Html.RenderSideMenu((ICollection<MyNamespace.MenuNode>)(ViewBag.Menu.LeftMenu));
    }
</div>
```

Also, as a side note, don't use `ViewBag`, use view models instead.

Comment: hm, so even if this menu is shown every time I should prepare viewModel? or make some generic class for ex. viewModel<TModel> which will have menu data?

Comment: @trn, yes, you should always use view models. Now because this is about some menu or something that should be repeated on each view, you probably have interest into placing it into the _layout of your site and use `Html.Action` in order to render it through a child controller action which will have a separate execution and view model from the main action. I would recommend you reading Phil Haak's blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx. Everytime you write `ViewBag`/`ViewData` in an ASP.NET MVC application say to yourself that you are doing it wrong.